# Script to trigger when a string appear in console program

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a program that generate strings in Windows. Each string appear after a certain time in a random order.

When the program.exe runs, I would to search the strings in real time, to trigger an action when "one specific string is detected".

script.bat:

```
run program.exe
if string "script three" is detected then echo "hello"
```

```
   program.exe
    time 1s : "string one" ............
    time 25s: "string two" ......................................
    time 1min50s : "string three" 
    hello
```

Comment: You can use `for /F` to capture the output of a program, but that doesn't finish looping until your program terminates.  What you're asking for will probably need to be handled by VBScript or JScript using [WshShell.Exec()](http://ss64.com/vb/exec.html) or similar.

Comment: What you want can be managed via a Batch file placed at right side of a pipe char: `program.exe | readLines.bat` and a simple read-line/test-line loop in the Batch file via `set /P`. However, if the strings may appear very fast, then part of them can be lost; just a test can confirm this point. Also, the read-test loop may end when an empty string is read, but if the program.exe may generate empty strings, then it would be necessary to implement a different method to end the program.

Comment: @rojo: A `for /F` based method don't works as the OP wants (_"search the strings in real time"_), because the first output line from the `for` command will be processed until the `program.exe` ends...

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: well i was talking of a windows based shell. Currently win10. I also realise that using the | in unix based system would be much more effective